# Fast Series and $\log 2$ irrationality

Tags: calculus

In a paper a new formula for the zeta function, I found the formula
$$1-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{4 i^{(k-1) k} \left(2 \sqrt{2}-3\right)^k (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor } \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right) \Gamma \left(2 \left\lfloor \frac{k-3}{2}\right\rfloor +5\right) \Gamma \left(2 \left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right)}{\left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right) \Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (k+3)}\\=\log 2$$
I realize using $k=10$ gives $12$ digits correct that seems a fast series in comparison with the Taylor series, is it possible to use it to show the irrationality of   $\log2$?

Comment: Do you mean $\log $ base $10$ or base $e$?  Either way, to use a series to show irrationality generally requires a very good handle on the error term for the partial sums (trusting that the partial sums are rational).  And there are easier proofs of irrationality (in either case).

Comment: And to prove irrationality, we would probably want a series of rationals, but maybe this is not, since it has $\sqrt{2}$ in there?

Comment: Edgar is right, although I suppose it's about accelerating the speed of convergence to demonstrate irrationality