# Recurrence relation of $1, 3, 3, 15, 5, 35, 7, 63, 9, 99, 11, 143, 13$

Tags: recurrence-relations, integers

> I found this sequence:
>   $$1,3,3,15,5,35,7,63,9,99,11,143,13,\ldots$$
>
> I'm looking for its recurrence relation, and/or its closed form.

---

**My take:** It's easy to see that when $n\geq4$ and is even, $a_n=a_{n-1}\cdot a_{n+1}$, and when $n\geq3$ and odd, then $a_n=n$. I'm having trouble to "combine" these observations into one recurrence relation.

**Add:** was able to write the recurrence relation as:
$$b_n=n^2-1+(-1)^n(b_{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)).$$
For $b_1=1$, though the resulting closed form doesn't look elementary. The generating function, using a CAS, is:
$$\frac{x^5+x^4-6 x^3-3 x-1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^3}.$$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/whats-wrong-with-asking-for-the-next-term-in-a-sequence

Comment: If this sequence was in the OEIS, it would merit the `dumb` keyword – it is not that interesting.

Comment: Where did this series come from?

Comment: A 'closed form' is simple: $a_n=\{n$, $n$ odd; $n^2-1$, $n$ even $\}$.  This is a perfectly legitimate closed form. If you mean a single algebraic expression, that's possible too - just manipulate $(-1)^n$ appropriately - but there's generally nothing at all to be gained by such manipulations.

Comment: @BrianTung I was looking at the first few terms of the summation in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862317/fast-series-and-log-2-irrationality), the sequence above appears in the denominator of each term

Comment: Actually, when $2|n,\quad a_n=(n+1)(n-1)=n^2-1$

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo yes, but I was hoping for a singular algebraic expression